# compare two MySQL tables with different types of data - JSON string array vs strings

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, mysql-json

Table A has one column 'phoneNumber' type string, Table B with column 'number' type JSON.
table B has one record with the value json array of phoneNumbers:
'["052669988", "0526635444"]'.
what is the best way to select all the values that Exist in table B but not Exist in table A?
I tried to extract the values with JSON_EXTRACT() - but how can i use them ?

table A:

| phoneNumber |
| --- |
| "052111111" |

table B:

| number |
| --- |
| '["052669988", "0526635444"]' |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT n.number
FROM tableB AS b
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(b.number, '$[*]' COLUMNS(
    number CHAR(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci PATH '$'
  )
) AS n
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA AS a ON n.number = a.PhoneNumber
WHERE a.id IS NULL;
```

JSON_TABLE() requires MySQL 8.0.

---

Since you commented that you are using MySQL 5.7, you can't use the solution above. You can either upgrade to 8.0 (fyi, 5.7 is end-of-life in October 2023, so you should be starting to think about upgrading before then anyway), or else find another solution.

What I would recommend is to *not* store data in JSON arrays.

If you were to store one phone number per row, then the solution would just be a simple outer join, comparing the number in one table to the number in the other table, and selecting where the other table is NULL because of the outer join.

```
SELECT b.number
FROM tableB AS b
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA AS a ON b.number = a.PhoneNumber
WHERE a.id IS NULL;
```

This solution works in any version of MySQL and it's easier to read and easier to optimize.

Comment: i have MySQL 8.0, and i get syntax error on JSON_TABLE

Comment: I did test the query I posted, and it has no error. What does `SELECT VERSION();` return in your environment? You may have the 8.0 client but it's the server that's important.

Comment: yeah my bad - the MySQL version is 5.7.12

Comment: the idea behind storing the values as a JSON array, is that table B is a temporary table, the insert query for inserting each number per row is too expensive for a big amount of numbers

Comment: Im getting an error - 
"Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' "
is the JSON_TABLE creating a table with collation `utf8mb4_general_ci`? if so, is there a way to change it ?

Comment: No, it should use whatever your session's `collation_connection` option is set to. You can specify the collation of the column defined in the JSON_TABLE(), I'll add that to the example above.

Comment: Or you can run `SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;` as an SQL statement in your session before you run the query. This will set the connection options.